# Copy/Rename Batch of Files, based on data in a worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have a list in Column A with hyperlinks of the file-names to PDF files on a shared network drive which gets filtered and sorted often. I want to run a macro on a selected filtered range excluding hidden rows in the table. The macro would copy those files to a new location, and rename them based on data in the worksheet.

Column A contains the hyperlinks file names including extension (e.g. Cell "A3" contains "15-P980_Vendor_15169_.pdf")
Column B and E contains text based on formula to extract text from the file name. The underscores are separators. (Column C and D are hidden and are not used). So, Cell "B3" contains "15-P980", and Cell "E3" contains "Vendor" from the file name that's in Column A.

[image]

Trying to rename the file in each row what's in Cell(, 5) + "_" + Cell(, 2) in the selected Range Rows.

I'm selecting my range as =$A$3:$E$6.

I am getting an Object required error. I'm having trouble writing the `For Each` part. Especially obtaining the file path, that is the `sourcePath =`. I figure I have to obtain the hyperlink address that's in Column A, then extract the file path from that, but not sure how to code that. Any help will be appreciated.

```
Sub CopyFile()
ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Unprotect
    On Error GoTo errHndl
    Dim xTitleId As String
    Dim sourcePath As String, destPath As String
    Dim sourceFile As String, destFile As String, sourceExtension As String
    Dim rng As Range, cell As Range, row As Range


    destPath = "C:\Users\\Desktop\Test\dst"
    sourceFile = ""
    destFile = ""

    xTitleId = "Copy/Rename Files"
    Set rng = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Application.Selection
    Set rng = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Application.InputBox("Range", xTitleId, rng.Rows, Type:=8)
    Set addr = rng.Cells(, 1)

    For Each row In rng.Rows
      sourcePath = addr.Hyperlinks(1).Address 
      sourceExtension = Split(row.Cells(, 1), ".")(1)
      sourceFile = sourcePath + row.Cells(, 1)
      destFile = destPath + row.Cells(, 5) + "_" + row.Cells(, 2) + "." +  sourceExtension
      File.Copy sourceFile, destFile, False
    Next row


    MsgBox "Operation was successful.", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Done"
    Exit Sub

errHndl:
    MsgBox "Error happened while working on: " + vbCrLf + _
        sourceFile + vbCrLf + vbCrLf + "Error " + _
        Str(Err.Number) + ": " + Err.Description, vbCritical + vbOKOnly, "Error"

End Sub
```

Comment: The "object required" error is raised because you are attempting to set `rng` to a text value in the InputBox method.

Comment: Can you please provide some additional guidance. I changed `Type:=2` to 8. Still getting error. Can you please provide help on extracting the file path from the hyperlink? I'm kind of stuck...

Comment: What's the purpose of the InputBox? How about something like `For Each myLink in rng.Hyperlinks`?

Comment: Also, is it possible for you to include samples from each column?

Comment: I added a link to the test workbook and an image of it. Thanks

Comment: I guess I can do away with the input box. I just need the range to be based on a selection.

Comment: Please see code revision. I'm getting Object Required error (also when I hit Cancel on the input box), and Type Mismatch error. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may or may not keep the input box. The input box range would be a selection of hyperlinks from column A only. Only thing that isn't working is the running this macro on a autofiltered range. I had it working for a bit, but when I cleared the auto filter and reapplied it, the macro included the hidden rows again. Not sure how to fix that...

Code Revision that also takes care of duplicates:

```
Sub CopyFile()
ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Unprotect
    On Error GoTo errHndl
    Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
    Dim xTitleId As String
    Dim sourcePath As String, destPath As String
    Dim sourceFile As String, destFile As String, sourceExtension As String
    Dim rng As Range, cell As Hyperlink, row As Range
    Dim i As Long


    destPath = "C:\Users\Accounting\Desktop\Invoices To Be Paid with Weekly Check Run\"
    sourceFile = ""
    destFile = ""

    xTitleId = "Copy file from hyperlink"
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set rng = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Application.Selection

    'On Error Resume Next
    'Set rng = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Application.InputBox("Range", xTitleId, rng.Address, Type:=8)
    'On Error GoTo 0

If rng.Hyperlinks.Count > 0 Then
 For Each cell In rng.Hyperlinks
    If Not rng.EntireRow.Hidden Then
        sourcePath = Left(cell.Address, Len(cell.Address) - Len(cell.TextToDisplay))
        sourceExtension = ".pdf"
        sourceFile = cell.Address
        destFile = destPath + Cells(cell.Parent.row, 5) + "_" + Cells(cell.Parent.row, 2) + sourceExtension
        i = 0
JumpHere:
        If Dir(destFile) = "" Then
        fso.CopyFile sourceFile, destFile, False
        Else
        i = i + 1
        destFile = destPath + Cells(cell.Parent.row, 5) + "_" + Cells(cell.Parent.row, 2) + "-" & i & sourceExtension
        GoTo JumpHere
        End If
    End If
 Next cell
Else
MsgBox "Cell does not contain a hyperlink"
Exit Sub
End If


    MsgBox "Operation was successful.", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Done"


    Exit Sub

errHndl:
    MsgBox "Error happened while working on: " + vbCrLf + _
        sourceFile + vbCrLf + vbCrLf + "Error " + _
        Str(Err.Number) + ": " + Err.Description, vbCritical + vbOKOnly, "Error"

End Sub
```

Correction:

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set rng = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Application.Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)



If rng.Hyperlinks.Count > 0 Then
 For Each hlink In rng.Hyperlinks
        sourcePath = Left(hlink.Address, Len(hlink.Address) - Len(hlink.TextToDisplay))
        sourceExtension = ".pdf"
        sourceFile = hlink.Address
        destFile = destPath + Cells(hlink.Parent.row, 5) + "_" + Cells(hlink.Parent.row, 2) + sourceExtension
        i = 0
JumpHere:
        If Dir(destFile) = "" Then
        fso.CopyFile sourceFile, destFile, False
        Else
        i = i + 1
        destFile = destPath + Cells(hlink.Parent.row, 5) + "_" + Cells(hlink.Parent.row, 2) + "-" & i & sourceExtension
        GoTo JumpHere
        End If
 Next hlink
Else
MsgBox "Selection does not contain a hyperlink"
GoTo Cancel
End If
```

Comment: I just changed `cell` to `hlink` instead

Comment: I'm glad you got it all figured out. Sorry I couldn't devote more time to personally help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure of what you're trying to accomplish but in order to extract the filename and path separately, instead of going through the range objects, I took the approach of looping through the hyperlink collection...

```
For Each linky In rng.Hyperlinks

    sourcePath = Left(linky.Address, Len(linky.Address) - Len(linky.TextToDisplay))

    sourceExtension = ".pdf" 'Split(row.Cells(, 1), ".")(1)
    sourceFile = linky.Address
    destFile = destPath + Cells(linky.Parent.row, 5) + "_" + Cells(linky.Parent.row, 2) + sourceExtension
    fso.CopyFile sourceFile, destFile, False
Next linky
```

You'll have to be careful about possible file duplication, which will raise an error. 
Also, I noticed you will likely need to add a `\` at the end of your `destpath`.

Comment: Thank you. I will test this soon. What I'm trying to accomplish is: I will have over 100 rows of links to pdf files that are in different folders. I want to collect a filtered range of links and copy those files to one folder renamed, so that they are in Vendor name order in that folder. I tend to allow duplicates. I have an IF statement that I need to embed in there to take care of that. Thanks much!

Comment: Got the code to copy a file. Some things that are not working: 1. I am getting a type mismatch error on: `destFile = destPath + Cells(cell.Parent.row, 5) + "_" + Cells(cell.Parent.row, 2) + i + "." + sourceExtension` . 2. It is copying all rows of a filtered range. I need it to exclude the hidden rows. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I've tried `If Not rng.EntireRow.Hidden Then` but that's not working. I'm applying an Autofilter, and then I want to run the code on only the visible rows.

Comment: Fixed the type mismatch error: Correct code is `destFile = destPath + Cells(cell.Parent.row, 5) + "_" + Cells(cell.Parent.row, 2) + "-" & i & sourceExtension`

Comment: Sorry I've been flying all day... In regards to working with the visible cells of the selected range, try `Set rng = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Application.Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)`

Comment: Thank you so much, it works. This is going to save me time.

Comment: There's a problem. If I only want to copy one, it copies all visible cells. I have to select one or more for it to work. I do I get around this problem?

Comment: Nevermind. Fixed it: `Set rng = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Application.Intersect(Selection, Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible))`